# как посмотреть список файлов внутри докер контейнера

Tags: docker

```
docker cp ./Views/Home/Index.cshtml exampleApp3000:/app/Views/Home/
```

эта команда мне выдает в командную строку о том, что такая дериктория не существует. 
Вопрос. Как посмотреть список доступных дерикторий внутри контейнера? Как мне понять, куда я могу переместить это?

Comment: можно плдключиться к контейнеру и посмотреть что лежит внутри.

Comment: Внутрь контейнера я вошел, как посмотреть его содержимое? Какой командой?

Comment: если контейнер на линуксе, то `ls` , если на windows, то `dir `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Выполнить любую команду в контейнере с выводом результата в терминал можно так:

```
docker exec -i -t <имя-или-id-контейнера> <команда>
```

Пример:

```
docker exec -i -t exampleApp3000 ls -alF /app
```

Команда выше должна вывести все файлы в директории /app внутри контейнера с именем exampleApp3000.

Точно так же можно создать недостающие директории в контейнере:

```
docker exec -i -t exampleApp3000 mkdir -p /app/Views/Home/
```